# I am trying to return all rows where there is more than n number of missing values, i would like to put these in a new data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

Obviously, the new data frame will have columns that do not contain any missing values.

```
generic = df.iloc[df['Current Age'] == isnull()]
```

This code does not work bc in=snull() is not defined, but basically, I am trying to find all the columns that have more than 6 missing values and put them into a new data frame called **generic**

Comment: please provide an example of the data and what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for posting your question here @Dan. Can you share some more details like the code you are using, expected output. This allows for users to provide a quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, let's imagine that we have a dataframe like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3, np.nan, 5, 3, np.nan], columns = ['value'])
```

np.isnan() returns true if the parameter is a NaN and when you filter a dataframe, it returns only the rows that are true based on your condition.

So, see the code bellow:

```
nanIndex = df[np.isnan(df['value'])].index.tolist() # Rows that contains NaN
newDF = df.drop(index = nanIndex) # Drop that rows, keep only non NaN rows
newDF.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True) # Reset the index of the dataframe
```